# How can I use instaceof in Django template?

Tags: python, django, class

Hello there I have a template that is used by two views in this template a have a toggle for deleting objects and because I have 2 types of objects that can be deleted by the same form I want to verify somehow the instance of the object in orderd to decide which url to use for deleting. How can I write this in django template properly?

```
 <form method="POST" action="{% if object instanceof Income %}{% url 'delete-income' object.id %}{% elif object instanceof Spending %}{% url 'delete-spending' object.id %}{% endif %}">
```

the views extend this custom mixin to not repeat code:

```
class ObjectDeleteViewMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = None
    template_name = 'users/incomes_&_spendings.html'
    success_url = None


    def test_func(self):
        self.model = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == self.model.user:
            return True
        return False
```

the views

```
class IncomeDeleteView(ObjectDeleteViewMixin):
    model = Income
    success_url = reverse_lazy('incomes')


class SpendingDeleteView(ObjectDeleteViewMixin):
    model = Spending
    success_url = reverse_lazy('spendings')
```

urls:

```
path('incomes/delete/<int:pk>/', IncomeDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete-income'),
    path('spendings/delete/<int:pk>/', SpendingDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete-spending'),
```

Comment: Please don't. This does *not* belong in the template, this is business logic. Furthermore it is rather odd that an object can be two different types, while not forbidden, it is often not a good idea.

Comment: Probably it is here better to simply implement a method for each class that points to the delete url.

Comment: I thought about something like this, to make just a single url for deleting the objects because the proces is the same but I really don't know how can I achive this in django

Comment: I'll add my views in the question and the urls, may you help me please?

Comment: You can create a custom template [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). But as @Willem Van Onsem said, this is not recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please *don't*. Django templates are deliberately restricted, *not* to allow function calls, subscripting, etc. to prevent people from writing business logic in the template. A template is normally focused on *rendering logic*. By implementing business logic in the template, you often make it templates harder to understand, update, etc.

Probably the most elegant way to solve this, is to define a method in both the `Income` and the `Spending` class that returns the path to the delete url:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class Income(models.Model):
    # …

    def remove_url(self):
        return reverse('delete-income', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

# …

class Spending(models.Model):
    # …

    def remove_url(self):
        return reverse('delete-spending', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

then you can render this with:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ object.remove_url }}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but what about the urls? How I am supposed to write them?

Comment: Or I'll leave they as are

Comment: @ARYAN: we already wrote them. By calling `object.remove_url`, we will retrieve the result of `reverse('delete-income', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})` for example, which is a path.

Comment: I understood now, I implemented it but it gives me this error now "'Income' object has no attribute '_default_manager'"

Comment: @ARYAN: but this normally has nothing to do with rendering the remove object, likely because you write `self.model = self.get_object()`, since `self.model` now is an *object*, you should not alter `self.object`.

Comment: @ARYAN: in fact it is probably *not* a good idea to use a `test_func` anyway, it might be better to filter the queryset such that it only can retrieve items for which the user is the owner: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipatterns/checking-ownership-through-the-userpassestestmixin.html